# How can I solve this sorting error?

Tags: c++

I want to write a program that in command line user will put the number of names they want to enter, and then they type those names with first and last names, Like following:

```
./Sort-names 5
Andrew Hawking
John Smith
Stephen Hawking
Alice Cooper
Jean Smith
```

And then I will get those inputs and sort them with last name in lexicographic order, so theout put should be:

```
Alice Cooper
Andrew Hawking
Stephen Hawking
Jean Smith
John Smith
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

//Identify space in a line
int locateLastName (char name[][20], int i, int j) {
    int locate = 0;

    while (name[i][j] && locate == 0) {
        if (isspace(name[i][j])) {
            locate = 1;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return j;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int x = atoi(argv[1]); //the number of names
    char name[x][20]; //names in 2d array
    char nameCopy[20]; //for bubble sort

    //get the input names
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cin.getline(name[i],20);
    }

    //bubble sort the last name
    for (int i = 0; i < x-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x-1; j++) {
            int a = locateLastName(name, j, 0);
            int b = locateLastName(name, j+1, 0);

            int haveChange = 0;
            while (name[j][a] && name[j+1][b] && haveChange == 0) {
                if (name[j][a] > name[j+1][b]) {
                    strcpy(nameCopy, name[j]);
                    strcpy(name[j], name[j+1]);
                    strcpy(name[j+1], nameCopy);

                    haveChange = 1;
                }
                a++;
                b++;
            }
        }
    }

    int line = 0;
    while (line < x) {
        cout << name[line] << endl;
        line++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, after my program is executed it produce the following result:

```
./Sort-names 5
Andrew Hawking  ->input
John Smith
Stephen Hawking
Alice Cooper
Jean Smith

John Smith      ->output
Andrew Hawking
Jean Smith
Stephen Hawking
Alice Cooper
```

Can anyone help me to find the bug, I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Best approach first is stepping through your code using the debugger and check where your code takes an unexpected path.

Comment: use `string`, `vector` and `sort`

Comment: In addition to @BLUEPIXY's advice, don't use `atoi` but `std::stoi`, don't use proprietary GCC variable-length arrays, don't use `cin.getline` but `std::getline`, don't use multi-dimensional arrays... Basically, don't use all those wrong pieces, because they make it harder to get to the real problem with your program logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard advice in a situation like this is to use a debugger and figure out what's going wrong.

IMO, in a case like this that's fairly poor advice. Even when you debug the code and correct the problem you've observed, it's still going to be code that (I hope) you won't like in a few months or so.

To make a long story short, you're not making very good use of the language and standard library--you're doing a lot of work to duplicate capabilities it already has ready for you to use, and you're using some non-standard (and non-portable) extensions of one specific compiler for no particularly good reason.

I'd probably do something more like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

// We'll use this a little later: just "eat" all the leading white-space
// from a stream.
std::istream &eat_whitespace(std::istream &is) {
    char ch;
    while (isspace(is.peek()))
        is.get(ch);
    return is;
}

// define a class to store, read, write, and compare people's names:
class name {
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
public:
    // Define how to read a name from a stream:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, name &n) {
        is >> n.first;
        eat_whitespace(is);
        return std::getline(is, n.last);
    }

    // likewise, how to write a name to a stream:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, name const &n) {
        return os << n.first << ' ' << n.last;
    }

    // Define how to compare two names. This will compare first by last name,
    // then if those are equal, first names:
    bool operator<(name const &other) const {
        if (other.last < last)
            return false;
        if (last < other.last)
            return true;
        return first < other.first;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Read the names from a file into a vector:
    std::vector<name> names { std::istream_iterator<name>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<name>() };

    // Sort them:
    std::sort(names.begin(), names.end());

    // Write out the results:
    for (auto const &n : names)
        std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

Probably the single most important point here is having encapsulated all the "knowledge" of a `name` into the `name` class. This lets the rest of the program just read, compare and write `name` as a complete things, instead of dealing with all the internal details of how a name is stored (and such). The rest of the program doesn't care (or need to know) anything about how a `name` works internally.

Also note how it's split up into a number of separate functions instead of having nearly everything in one giant function. In this case, each function is so small and simple (and its purpose simple enough) that for nearly all of them, most real problems would be pretty obvious almost at first glance.

Then there's that last piece: leaving as much of the work as we can to the standard library. Just for the most obvious example, it already has code to sort things--we don't need to write a sort of our own.